Probability of buying lunch

Alice is equally likely to pack or buy lunch every day. Over the course of the next $7$ days, she buys lunch $4$ times. Assuming her decision is independent between the days, what is the probability that in the first $3$ days she bought lunch exactly $2$ times?

I thought of 2 ways to solve this problem and I am not sure which one is right.
Approach $1$:
Since it's given Alice is equally likely to pack or buy lunch. I assume,
$P($Buying lunch$) = P($Packing lunch$) = \frac{1}{2}$
Then,
$ P($$2$ Buys in first $3$ days | $4$ Buys in $7$ days$) = P($$4$ Buys in $7$ days | $2$ Buys in first $3$ days$) \times P($$2$ Buys in $3$ days$)$/$ P($$4$ Buys in $7$ days$)$

$P($$4$ Buys in $7$ days | $2$ Buys in first $3$ days$)= \frac{4C_2}{2^4}$

We know in the first $3$ days, Alice buys $2$ times, hence, we look for the probability she buys twice in the next $4$ days.

$P($$2$ Buys in first $3$ days$)= \frac{3C_1}{2^3}$


$P($$4$ Buys in first $7$ days$)= \frac{7C_4}{2^7}$

$ P($$2$ Buys in first $3$ days | $4$ Buys in $7$ days$) = \frac{\frac{6}{2^4} \times \frac{3}{2^3}}{\frac{35}{2^7}}$
$ P($$2$ Buys in first $3$ days | $4$ Buys in $7$ days$) = \frac{18}{35}$
Approach $2$:
Since, the event she buys lunch in the first $3$ days is independent of her buying lunch in the later 4 days.
$ P($$2$ Buys in first $3$ days | $4$ Buys in $7$ days$) = P($$2$ Buys in first $3$ days$)$
$ P($$2$ Buys in first $3$ days | $4$ Buys in $7$ days$) = \frac{3C_2 \times 4C_2}{7C_4} = \frac{18}{35}$
What is the correct answer to this?

Approach $2$ is definitely not correct. What she does in the first three days definitely depends on what she does in the first $7$ days, because those three days are literally contained in the $7$ days.

I don't understand your second method  There are $\binom 74$ equally probable ways to pick the four purchase days.  There are $\binom 32\times \binom 42$ ways to do it that pass the test.

Oh yes, sorry my answer is incomplete in approach 2. Fixed it now!

All necessary material for the correct answer has already been given in the comments by lulu. Why can't you calculate and check by yourself ?

To check if a reasoning is correct, it is often good to change some numerical values, and apply the same reasoning, with some 'extreme values'. For example, Over the course of the next (next or last ?) 7 days, she buys lunch not 4 times, but 6 times ... or even 0 times. With extreme values it is easy to check if the reasoning gives something consistant.
